# ASP.NET core Web api debugging tempalted code is not working as it is explained in documetns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn asp.net core web api development. And as usual, I started with debugging the template project generated by VS 2019. But the test page which is appearing when I debug, is not the same as described on the tutorials. It is annoying and after wasting several hours with googling I decided to ask stackoverflow. Which configration am I missing?

The test/output page When I debug: ( actually there is not any button.)
[image]

However the expected web page is as shown in the
[image]

Note: the picture of expected webpage is taken from: [The video is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA5Fyt8sM7Y&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oVjOKgzsWqdFVvzGL2_d72v&index=3&t=8s)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are these supposed to be the same page? They have completely different URLs. One is an HTML endpoint (and ends with `.html`.) and the other seems to be a JSON endpoint (with no extension on the end of the URL).

Comment: Thank you. But as @Yinqui explained this is related with SwaggerUI support. and actually it is coming automatically, if .NET 5 is targettted and OpenAPI is opted in when you create the new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, these are two different pages, you can enter the url:`https://localhost:xxxxx/swagger/index.html`to reach the expected SwaggerUI page.

About [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware).

> Launch the app, and navigate to localhost:/swagger/v1/swagger.json. The generated document describing the endpoints appears as shown in OpenAPI specification (openapi.json).

If you want to set SwaggerUI as default start page.You can change the property in your `launchSettings.json file`.

Open the launchSettings.json file.Change the `launchUrl` property to `swagger`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see it is all related with OpenAPI support and its added by default if .NET5 and OpenAPI support seleceted.